# Does this code have only one level of abstraction?

Tags: clean-code, code-smell

I'm trying to apply some good practices from Clean Code in my code, but I'm stuck trying to figure out if my code has a [G34] code smell, which tells that functions should descend only one level of abstraction.

```
var tryToMakeAMove = function(line, column) {
  if( board[line][column] === EMPTY) {
    makeMoveInPosition(line, column);
    drawBoard();
    verifyWinner();
    changePlayer();
  }
  else {
    changeStatusMessage("Invalid Move!");
  }
}
```

I'm doing too much in this function or it is okay to call all those functions in the `if` block? If I'm doing too much, how could I refactor this function to do only one thing?

Comment: Seems like CodeReview is more suitable place for this questions.

Comment: @Fabio we are allowed to look at code here.  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) tends to be for open ended reviews.  This question is nicely focused on one concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a student of Clean Code myself. Here's my attempt at Uncle Bob's style.

```
var takeTurn = function(line, column) {
  if( moveIsValid(line, column) ) {
    move(line, column);
    verifyWinner();
    changePlayer();
  }
  else {
    changeStatusMessage("Invalid Move!");
  }
}
```

First we must decide what level of abstraction we're working at.  Most of the work here isn't about the move but basic turn taking. The `if` condition ties us to details of move rules and not turn taking so I've abstracted that away with a function.

That free's this function of other move concerns that might need to be added like a check against moving a queen like knight, a check if the user is illegally attempting to capture their own pieces, diagonally moving a pawn that isn't capturing, castling after the king has moved, etc.

Is it now at one level of abstraction? Well updating the board after a move is not about turn taking. So I've pushed `drawBoard()` down into `makeMoveInPosition()`

`verifyWinner()` and `changePlayer()` are about turn taking.  For instance what if you decide the consequence for making an invalid move is loosing a turn or loosing the the game? Chess is sometimes played that way. So I think it's fine to have them here where they can be moved around at will.

I've also renamed the function so that anyone looking inside the function for the first time wont be surprised that it's full of turn taking logic and not move logic.  That follows something called [the principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  It's nice when you look in a function and it does pretty much what you expected.  The best way to foster that is give the function a good name and be faithful to it's meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question. In the page 35 of Clean Code at Blocks and Indenting, Uncle Bob say your fuctions should be short as possible and it implies `if`, `else` and `while` blocks should be 1 line long using a good descriptive function to tell the intention of the block. Is it really necessary in this case and if yes, which name should I give to that function?

Comment: @kewersonhugo it's only necessary if you mean to follow that style.  It isn't an issue of level of abstraction as turning a nameless abstraction into a named abstraction.  You can do that.  It is a style that demands many names of you. Off the top of my head `successTurn()` and `failTurn()` come to mind.  So do `validMove()` and `invalidMove()`. But as you build the rest of the code expect to need to reexamine your names as you discover your real needs.

Comment: I am pretty sure Uncle Bob would not *"push `drawBoard` down into `makeMoveInPosition`"*, he would probably keep these two things separated and make a new function which calls both in sequence (your `move` function` could be this function). I would also expect him to group the call sequence `move`, `verifyWinner` and `changePlayer` into a new function, just not sure how to name it, something like `executeMoveTurn` maybe.

Comment: But, @DocBrown, updating the board state isnt part of accomplishing a `move`? The `drawBoard` will just present the new state from the board.
And I like the idea of `executeMoveTurn` to keep the `if` block small. It feels more readable.

Comment: @kewersonhugo: where did I write "updating the board state isnt part of accomplishing a move"? I said "makeMoveInPosition" and "drawBoard" might be grouped together by a function which calls both in sequence (opposed to "makeMoveInPosition is mixed up with drawBoard", as this answer suggests).

Comment: Sorry if it sounded wrong. I was just wondering if `drawBoard` does not belong to `makeMove` responsibility.

Comment: I'm not sure that `drawBoard` belongs in this module at all, to be honest - it feels like it should be its own thing, probably using the Observer pattern to learn a about changes to the board so that it never has to be dealt with at this level of abstraction.

Comment: @Jules it comes down to whether `drawBoard()` depends on the move being valid.  If we're allowed to ignore that and call it after every turn it doesn't need to be down here at all. Either way I don't like looking at it here.

Answer (score 3):

#### Level of abstraction

I would consider the if statement in line 1

```
if( board[line][column] === EMPTY)
```

and the changeStatusMessage() call

```
changeStatusmessage("Invalid Move!")
```

as a lower level of abstraction then the other ones. The other ones are rather abstract, there are no implementation details visible. But the given two lines are pretty low level. My advice for the first refactoring would be

```
if( boardIsEmpty(line, column) )
```

and

```
showInvalidMoveError()
```

#### Doing one thing

As for how much you are doing I indeed would say you are doing too much. You *check for an empty board* and then *execute a move* or else *show an error*. The execution however is split into several steps, which in this sense could also be a different kind of abstraction. So consider todo another refactoring:

```
if( isValidMove(line, column) )
    executeMove(line, column);
else
    showInvalidMoveError();
```

One might even argue that it is still to much doing, as you are also *handling an error*.

So I would maybe just through an error like this

```
else throw Error(INVALID_MOVE);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing it to call `boardIsEmpty` or `showInvalidMoveError`. Your "doing one thing" code is better - especially as you renamed `boardIsEmpty` to `isValidMove`.

Comment: Invalid move is part of the execution control. Changing it to throwing exceptions force you to catch that exception. Which makes you using exceptions as control flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @immibis. I considered throwing a expcetion in the `else` block too, but as stated by @fabio, displaying the invalid move to users is part of the application normal flow.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the names of the functions I believe the functions

```
drawBoard();
verifyWinner();
changePlayer();
```

are already at a different abstraction layer than `tryToMakeAMove()` which seems like a much lower level, yet also appears to be a mix of responsibilities.

If your program is asking for input in a loop until a valid move is provided, then that whole process should be it's own function existing at the same level as the functions I mentioned. That process can be organized into:

1. Collect player input
2. Validate the input
3. If invalid/show message, else perform the move
4. Repeat until there's a valid move

```
function move(player, board) {
  let moveIsValid == false;
  while(!moveIsValid) {
    const {line, column} = collectUserInput(player);
    const moveIsValid = isMoveValid(line, column, board);
    if(!moveIsValid) {
      changeStatusMessage("Invalid Move!");
    } else {
      updateBoardWithMove(line, column, board);
    }
  }
}
```

And isMoveValid could be:

```
function(line, column, board) {
 return board[line][column] === EMPTY
}
```

And finally the top level would look like this:

```
let currentPlayer = 'Player1';
let winner = undefined;
const board = new Board();
while (!winner) {
  move(currentPlayer, board);
  drawBoard(board);
  winner = verifyWinner(board);
  currentPlayer = changePlayer(currentPlayer);
}
celebrate(winner);
```